# How to sign up for Jira?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

Is this correct that Jira is installed on one's server or local computer and that's the only way to run it?

If not, how can I run, or connect to, Jira on Atlassian's server?

Namely, at this point I don't want to install anything on **my VPS or computer**, and instead I want to be able to run Jira in the cloud, **the same way I'd sigu up for and then use bitbucket or github**. That is, by creating an account. I need Jira for a couple of days only, to test some REST API.

Where does one sign up for Jira? There's no way, is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the current time Atlassian provides a free plan for its Jira cloud service.
See here: https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/pricing